# Display Content only if a user "wins"

Tags: javascript, html, css

having a bit of trouble.
im trying to creat a play again button the appears only when the user wins,
i've set the condition of the div to visibility:none when the user won,
else its in display:none
however, the button always appears, right from the start, any advice?
the audio plays correctly, only when the user wins.
so i got this piece of code in html:

```
<div id="Again">
  <button type="button" onclick="toggle_visibility">Play Again</button>
  </div>
```

and the following in js:

```
function toggle_visibility(id) {
            var x = document.getElementById('Again');
            if (TOTAL_COUPLES_COUNT === flippedCouplesCount) {
            audioWin.play();
            x.style.display = 'block';}
            else {
                x.style.display = 'none';

            }
```

Answer (score 1):

The initial display state of the `button` should be *none*. Here's a skeleton snippet that may help you along:

```js
const button = document.querySelector("button");
const input = document.querySelector("input");
const inputHandler = evt => {
  if (+evt.target.value == guessValue) {
    button.classList.replace("hidden", "visible");
  } else {
    button.classList.replace("visible", "hidden");
  }
};
let guessValue = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 10);

button.addEventListener("click", () => {
  button.classList.replace("visible", "hidden");
  input.value = "";
  guessValue = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 10);
});

input.addEventListener("change", inputHandler);
input.addEventListener("keyup", inputHandler);
```

```css
button.hidden {
  display: none
}

button.visible {
  display: inline-block
}
```

```html
<input type="number" max="10" min="1"> Guess a number (1 - 10)
<button class="hidden">Again?</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

The button is visible since the beginning because it has neither an "hardcoded" `style` attribute which says to hide it or a `CSS` proprerty which does the same. The JS code which "toggles" the button is only triggered when pressed, so it has no effect as the page loads.

Comment: thanks, can u show me that in code perhaps? would be alot easier to understand